# Chord arpeggiator plugin

Tags: midi, vst, plugin

I'm looking for a arpeggio/stepsequencer plugin which repeats all played notes in an interval simultaniously. This way I can draw chords in my midi sequencer and determine the rythm with this plugin. The arpeggiator of ableton has all the options I need except it will allways play one note. Also kirnu cream doesn't seem to be able to do this.

Any advice is welcome, thank you.

Bas

Answer (score 1):

[Cthulhu](https://xferrecords.com/products/cthulhu) by XferRecords is a really nice arp VST. Moreover it is a chord engine as well, which means you can select a chord set from the presets (or create your own) and then you can play one key chords and you can arpeggiate these chords using the in-built arp engine.

Comment: I second this, Cthulu is a beast